# Why is CPU % Decreasing At Highest User Load During Load Testing?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2008, load-testing

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I am load testing my .NET Web API  which is hosted on a Windows 2008 Server virtual machine. I am using Visual Studio 2012 Load Test. However, once my load test reaches 780 concurrent users, the CPU % starts to decrease as shown in the image attached. The load test reaches a maximum of 1000 concurrent users but the CPU % is still decreasing at the highest user load. I cannot explain why. Is any kind of IIS limit being reached? Why does this occur? Is the maximum user load reached for this function?  [image]

Just looking for an explanation to this result and some guidance.

Thank you

Comment: thread pooling possibly?

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: A few questions:
What test mix type are you using? (assuming most likely user paced)
Do you have a max set of test iterations perhaps?
Do you have a means of validating that the users are still doing the intended work, at the desired pace/rate, when at the max user load?

Comment: Is there a chance you have any type of caching that has to occur during the early part of your test execution, that is complete by the time all the users are logged in?

Comment: The total test duration shown is only about 15 minutes. That means the rate of increase of virtual users is very high. So @Daileyo's comment about caching is well worth investigating. What is the duration of an individual test? I would recommend rerunning the test but making the ramp up much slower. If one test takes N seconds to execute then increase by 100 virtual users every 3N to 5N seconds. That way you get a steady state load at each user level.

Comment: I would also suggest a first test that increases by 20 users every 3N to 5N seconds to a maximum of 200 users, to get confidence that the system works for a modest user load and that the test suite delivers sensible results.

Comment: itS possible that a bunch of threads are being created to satisfy demand, then they are pooled so that they can be reused.  Im just guessing, but I would suspect that the initial CPU increase is due to the creation of those threads, and you see the decrease because those threads are being re-used opposed to new ones being created.

Comment: IIS caching was enabled, I wasn't aware that IIS was able to cache.

Comment: It could also be that your app is I/O bound, rather than CPU bound, such that past a certain point your CPU starts to sit idle part of the time because it's waiting on contention for disk or network resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS does have separate output cache settings which are enabled by default which does start to make sense after considering how it handles dynamic content with static response and cache worthiness:

> The IIS output caching feature targets semi-dynamic content. It lets
> you cache static responses for dynamic requests and increase
> scalability
>
> **Configuring Cache Worthiness:**
>
> Even if you enable output caching, IIS does not immediately cache a
> request. It must be requested a few times before IIS considers a
> request to be “cache worthy.” Cache worthiness can be configured via
> the ServerRuntime section.
>
> Two properties determine cache worthiness:
>
> frequentHitTimePeriod
> frequentHitThreshold
>
> A request is only cached if more than frequentHitThreshold requests  for a cacheable URL arrive within the frequentHitTimePeriod.

This was a good explanation: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching